# Grouping checks with completeness-fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using [completeness-fu 0.6.0](https://github.com/joshk/completeness-fu) with mongoid 2.0.1 and rails 3.0.4

Using completeness-fu is easy and quick and gives many options like caching results, getting absolute score, getting percent completeness, failed checks etc. Its a wonderful gem.

My problem that the user profile is really bulky, therefore it has been divided into sections. I need to calculate the completeness score for individual sections along with a completeness score of full profile. I can't figure out how should it be done.

Thanks!